# Dryer voltage not right

Tags: dryer, voltage

My dryer won’t start. I’ve had the timer switch replaced and still nothing. The outlet in the wall reads the 240/120/120 from both the socket itself and the backside. The plug for the dryer is reading 240/240/9. Appliance repair tech said it’s a problem with either the breaker or the wall outlet and the landlord is telling me it’s a problem with the dryer.  Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Is this three wire or four wire?  Sounds like three wire.  Where are you reading dryer plug voltage, at plug or dryer?

Comment: It’s a 3 prong.  Did the readings at both I think. I’m not super good with this kinda of stuff. The wall outlet is reading the 240/120/120. Where the plug is wired to the dryer reads 240/240/9 and if I plug the dryer into the outlet and test the prongs on the plug it’s 240/240/9.

Comment: Would check dryer cable for broken wire, with it removed from dryer and outlet.  Use ohm range on meter and bend/move cable for testing.

Comment: When you say cable are you meaning the plug?

Comment: Plug and wire/cable that goes from outlet to dryer.  Take picture of how cable is attached to dryer first.

Comment: Defintely check the dryer cord for a broken wire, and *DO NOT USE THE DRYER* until this is fixed, as the chassis is currently LIVE/HOT whenever the dryer's plugged in!

Comment: So we replaced the plug and the voltage is right now but still won’t start. Any next step suggestions?